# MySQL - Query not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
if($GetSize != ""){
    $r = mysql_query("select * from `ProductSizes` ps, `products` p WHERE `ps.Size`='$GetSize' and `p.id`=`ps.Product`");

} else {
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `Category`='$Cat' $FilterSQL $FilterSQLS $BrandSearch ORDER $OrderBy LIMIT $first_product_shown1, $products_per_page");
}


while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {

        $id = $rowi['id'];
        $Title = $rowi['Title'];
        $Image = $rowi['Image'];
        $Price = $rowi['Price'];
        $PriceOld = $rowi['PriceOld'];
        $Rating = $rowi['Rating'];
        $SDProductCode = $rowi['ProductCode'];
        $Lev = $Price * GetSetting('PoundRate');
        $LevOld = $PriceOld * GetSetting('PoundRate');
        $Lev = number_format($Lev, 2, '.', '');
        $LevOld = number_format($LevOld, 2, '.', '');
}
```

I think i have some mistake in it because i get no results.

Do you find any mistake and how the fixed variant must look like ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with reading manuals. Again.

Comment: first you do the "joins" then the "where". also try the queries in a mysql prompt to get error messages.

Comment: Always good to test your queries on the database first before you include them in code. You'll find mistakes much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `WHERE` clause before `JOIN`:

Correction:

```
mysql_query("
select * from `ProductSizes` c 
join `products` o on o.`id` = c.`Product` 
WHERE `c.Size` = '$GetSize'
");
```

**Side Note:**

I suggest you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` becuase it's deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: @TonyStark: Product in products table is your product id??

Comment: Please check again my updated question.

Comment: remove backtickles, trty this:     $r = mysql_query("select * from ProductSizes ps, 
    products p WHERE ps.Size = '$GetSize' and p.id = ps.Product");  @TonyStark

Comment: @TonyStark  and also check error by runing manualy query in your phpmyadmin.     select * from ProductSizes ps, products p WHERE ps.Size = '1' and p.id = ps.Product

Comment: @TonyStark .. can u share the result

Answer (score 0):

Consider modifying your query like below cause your query syntax is wrong. `JOIN` clause should come before `WHERE`

```
select c.* 
from `ProductSizes`  c 
join `products` o on o.`id` = c.`Product`
WHERE c.`Size` = '$GetSize';
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL query seems to be incorrect... try this

```
mysql_query("select * from `ProductSizes` ps, `products` p WHERE `ps.Size`='$GetSize' and p.`id`=ps.`Product`")
```

Also a good idea to check MySQL query result using mysql_query_error function

```
if(mysql_query_error()) {
    //Probably syntax error
}
```

Comment: What is not working? sql statement or mysql_query_error function?

Comment: The sql statement is not working.

Comment: Please check again my updated question.

Comment: does your statement work? I mean, not talking about returning results but syntactically correct

Comment: The sql statement is not working

Comment: Yours? what's mysql error? syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("select * from `ProductSizes` c join `products` o on o.`id`=c.`Product` WHERE c.`Size`='$GetSize'")
```

Comment: Why you have double `on on` in your answer ?